# how convert dictionary to vtk file for plotting 3D mesh

Tags: python, plot, 3d, mesh, vtk

I have dataset for 3D mesh saved as .npz file which is dictionary, the keys are  (vertices, faces, texture,...) and the values are a 3D numpy array. I want to plot the 3D object in .npz file so I Through to convert .npz to vtk file and then visualize it. I tried a lot of methods but doesn't works, plz someone who can help to resolve this issue. Thank u in advance.

Comment: You say you tried a lot of methods - share the one you had the best hopes for and perhaps someone here can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio/).

Comment: More options are [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/blob/master/vtkplotter/examples/basic/buildmesh.py) or [pyvista](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista).